# Use sans-serif font for sidenotes in the Tufte-book class

Tags: fonts, tufte, sidenotes

Using the `caption` package I have managed to change the font for captions that go along images and tables:

`\usepackage[font={sf,scriptsize,stretch=1.25}]{caption}`

But this doesn't also change the sidenote font. How could I match the two?

I am getting this:

[image]

The note on top is a regular `\sidenote{...}`, while the second note is generated by a `\caption{...}`.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Although your question didn't require much code, it's really helpful for future question to provide a small compilable  example document (like the one in my answer) for people to play with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tufte` classes provide commands for
customizing the marginal material. They are:

```
   \setsidenotefont{}
   \setcaptionfont{}
   \setmarginnotefont{}
   \setcitationfont{}
```

So in your case, you want to use the first two commands although if you're independently using the `caption` package, then it's better to use its commands for the captions.

```
\documentclass[marginals=auto]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsidenotefont{\sffamily}
\setcaptionfont{\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]\sidenote{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3]
\begin{marginfigure}\caption{A caption}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]