# Font size changes when printing PDF, but not when viewing it on screen

Tags: pdf, fontsize, overleaf, tufte, printing

I have a very large and complex `tufte-book` document. I have not been able to pinpoint what causes the issue I am reporting here, so for now, I can not provide an MWE... but maybe this is a known problem?

Following Alan Munn's [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576302/165913), I have set up a different font for sidenotes. It is a custom font, so:

```
\setsansfont[
    Numbers=Proportional,
    Path=./inter/,
    BoldFont=Inter-Bold,
    ItalicFont=Inter-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Inter-BoldItalic,
    Scale=MatchUppercase
]{Inter-Regular}
```

and

```
\setsidenotefont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\setcaptionfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\setmarginnotefont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\setcitationfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
```

This works to make my sidenotes have the correct font in the correct size:

[image: Screenshot of a document. We can see a part of the main text column and a sidenote. The font between the two is different.]

This was all fine and dandy. Or so I thought, because when I printed the PDF:

[image: Photo of the document shown before.]

This happens all over the document. I use this sans-serif font for my page numbers, for instance, and they too are enormous.

Has anyone ever had this issue before?

(I am compiling the PDF in XeLaTeX mode @ Overleaf.)

Comment: Out of curiousity what PDF software are you using to print the PDF? I once had a problem like this a long time ago, but only on some PDF software; it turns out the PDF viewer didn't properly support the units the font maker chose for their metrics. It was really a bug with the PDF software, but it could be worked aorund by changing the metrics units in the font.

Comment: I can't replicate that setup anymore, but from what I recall I tried opening the PDF in both Adobe Acrobat and Mac's native PDF viewer, where it showed up fine. The printer was some inkjet from HP, but I don't know the model.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave this unanswered because I would still like to find out what is happening, but I converted the OTF font file to TTF (through the [Convertio online service](https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/)) and the printed PDF is now matching its screen version.

I had downloaded the original OTF font [here](https://rsms.me/inter/), but what really bugs me is that when I tried doing an MWE with the same font it printed out fine, so the issue seems to be with some other package I am using.

It is nevertheless very hard to debug because I have to print the file each time I make a change, so now that it is working I will leave it as it is... ‍♂️